# Access AWS API Gateway from an intranet via a Firewall Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, firewall, rest

We have an on-prem Qlik Sense server located on the intranet that has no internet connection by default. We have a DynamoDB on AWS to which we need to access via Rest API with AWS Gateway and Lambda functions in a VPC.

The only way we can access the internet thru the Qlik Server is if we define a static IP address and a port to be whitelisted thru a Firewall rule. How can we achieve this? We have the following architecture in mind. Would it work?
[image]

I am quite new to the AWS world, so please excuse me if the question sounds very amateur. Should you need further explanation, please let me know.

Comment: What we want to achieve is partly covered in this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/expose-aws-lambda-function-behind-static-ip-when-a-dns-cannot-be-managed/

Comment: So what's not working from the tutorial that's causing issues? I can't see api gateway in this diagram so how's it working? API GW and Lambda don't technically sit in your VPC so maybe you're using a VPC or ALB to handle it.